# Guice bind abstract base class to concrete class

Tags: java, guice

I have a module with the following bindings

```
bind(BaseAbstract.class).to(Concrete.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(Concrete.class).toProvider(.....);
```

When I asks Guice to provide me two classes, one needs base, one needs Concrete, two separate Concrete objects are created.

```
injector.getInstance(INeedABaseAbstract.class);
injector.getInstance(INeedAConcrete.class);
```

I want only once single Concrete instance that Guice will give to classes needing a BaseAbstract or a Concrete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're binding `BaseAbstract` as a `Singleton` instead of `Concrete`. Try this:

```java
bind(BaseAbstract.class).to(Concrete.class);
bind(Concrete.class).toProvider(ConcreteProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```